# How to pragmatically open a drop down from another component in Vue with MDB Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, ref, mdbootstrap

I am trying to open a MDB dropdown menu once I click on a modal button. The modal is a separate component. How can I communicate between the 2 components?

```
<mdb-dropdown>
                <!-- Shopping Cart Button -->
                <mdb-dropdown-toggle class="pl-0" ref="toggle" slot="toggle">
                    <a>
                        <span class="fa-stack">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i id="cartTotal" style="font-size: 14px;" class="fa fa-stack-1x">{{$store.state.cartLength}}</i></span>
                    </a>
                </mdb-dropdown-toggle>
```

I am able to open it in the same component by using and it works but I have to be able to open it from another component:

```
 mounted() {   
    this.$refs.toggle.$el.click();
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) is the go-to for Vue state management.  There are some other options like [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) or an event bus, but Vuex is generally the way to go.

Comment: How would a refrence this.$refs.toggle.$el.click(); utilizing Vuex?